How can I resize the popup of LocalDateTimePicker?
When I click on the clock icon a date-time-selector is popup'ed.
The popup's size is such that it hides the time picker (the slider at the bottom). I need to resize the popup (not the textfield). Obviously this css resizes the textfield:
.LocalDateTimeTextField {
 -fx-min-width: 1000px;
}

The time slider has a large-ish font but a lot of it is obscured because of the popup's small size. So I can not be sure if this is a font-not-found problem where the replacement messes up the slider.
I have tried changing the picker's locale to Locale.ENGLISH (from greek). It's the same size, same obscured time-slider.

After re-reading this
How can I access the CSS style of the popup control with LocalDateTimePicker
I altered the size of the popup using this css:
.CalendarPicker {
 -fx-min-width: 1000px;
}

